# DIVs overlapping when I use float

Tags: html, overlap

I'm trying to get 2 divs to sit side by side, a div for an ad (skyscraper_ad), and a main black (smaller_main) but when I add a float the DIV will overlap another DIV, can somebody help?

My css:

```
#skyscraper_ad {
     display: block;
     width: 160px;
     height: 600px;
     padding: 5px;
     margin-right: auto;
     background-color: #CCCCCC;
     border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
     position:relative;
     margin-bottom: 4px;
}

#smaller_main {
     display: block;
     width: 605px;
     height: auto;
     background-color: #CCCCCC;
     border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
     position:absolute;
     padding: 5px;
     float: right;
     margin-bottom: 4px;
}
```

Comment: Why are you mixing up floating with absolute positioning?

Comment: I was trying everything to try to get them to sit side by side, I truthfully don't understand positioning :/

Comment: Czechnology noted, your CSS doesn't make much sense, if your new to CSS, I suggest using Firebug, it's an add-on for Firefox, which I and a lot of developers use to style webpages... 
www.getfirebug.com/ - So give that a go, and do a bit of a google on Positioning.

Comment: I'm fairy recent with CSS, I just don't understand positioning, even with the code that was given below the problem still occurs =[

Comment: I still don't understand why floated divs are overlapping into other divs though.

Comment: @Aiden Ryan, do you have a live example of your problem? Or are you able to reproduce it on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
#skyscraper_ad {
     width: 160px;
     height: 600px;
     padding: 5px;
     background-color: #CCCCCC;
     border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
     margin-bottom: 4px;
     float:left;
}

#smaller_main {
     width: 605px;
     background-color: #CCCCCC;
     border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
     padding: 5px;
     float: left;
     margin-bottom: 4px;
}
```

I took out your references to margin, positioning, and display. (and a `height:auto` which was meaningless as far as i could see).  The margin auto was meaningless, the positioning was probably causing overlap, and the display was redundant (`div`s are already block)